# Update to Symfony 2.8 SQLSTATE exception

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo, dbal, symfony-2.8

Today I updated one of my projects to the new **symfony version 2.8** since the update the shell is trowing this exception when running the **`cache:clear`** command:

> An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect
>   to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Any clues how to solve this issue or is it a bug caused by the new symfony version?

Comment: Has your parameters.yml file been overrun? Check if it has necessary parameters for database connection.

Comment: Which version of doctrine are you using?  It should be at least 2.4.8.  A plain symfony 2.8 install works fine.  Maybe post the require section of composer.json or compare with the github version.

Comment: outdated doctrine package seems to be the problem